# Counting groups of values in a column that are less than a cutoff

Tags: bash

I have a long file with 3 columns like this

```
2       189939871       21
2       189939872       21
2       189939873       19   ##########
2       189939874       19   ## Here there is one
2       189939875       18   ##########
2       189939876       23
2       189939877       30
2       189939878       15   ##########
2       189939879       15   ## Here there is the second one
2       189939880       24
2       189939881       12   ## The third one
2       189939882       30
2       189939883       10   ##########
2       189939883       10   ##########
2       189939883       10   ##########
2       189939883       10   ## the last one
2       189939883       10   ##########
```

I want to count the number of times there is gaps in the third column that are less than 20. (I have put comments on the right of the example to show you what I mean).

I have been thinking for a while but I don't even know how to do this. The desired results would be 4.

EDIT (For a better explanation.

For gaps I mean, each time there is a number or group of number than are less than 20. In the example above the first gap appear in the third line to the 5th line. That is a gap. Then the second gap in the example starts in the 8th to the 9th line. A gap can be also form by a single number that is less than 20. An example is given in the line 11. And the last gap is formed by 5 lines from the 13th line to the end

Comment: Why isn't there one between 18 and 23, between 23 and 30. And the gap between 30 and 10 is exactly 20, which isn't less than 20, so why is there one there?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _"gaps [..] that are less than 20"_

Comment: so a `gap` is a set of consecutive lines where all of the numbers in the 3rd column are less than 20 ... ?

Comment: I am new in this community. I have read the recommendation for writing questions and I think I follow these recommendation. I don't know the answer and I dont know how to start with. Could you give a feedback of why this has been mask negatively.

Comment: @Pinocho I don't think that your question is a duplicate but there's a lot people that ask about the processing of tabular data with the shell. The first clause of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is __search and research__, and IMO with a little effort on your part you would have found out that there are tools like `awk` for doing that. BTW, from what I understood, you're looking for the _number of blocks of contiguous values under 20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '$3<20&&(p>=20||p==""){c++}{p=$3}END{print c}' file
```

Output on your sample data:

```
4
```